# Interpolate function against time

Tags: list-manipulation, interpolation, vector

I have two vectors called lammdaWind11 and timeWind11. They are of size 51*1. I have interpolted each one independently as

```
lammdaWind11I = ListInterpolation[lammdaWind11];
```

and

```
timeWind11I = ListInterpolation[timeWind11];
```

However, I can find the values compared to the element of the vector. I want to put the time vector in the X axis and the lammda as the y variable so that I can know the value of the function for a certain time, not for an element of the vector. Unfortunately, I cannot find naything about this in [the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListInterpolation.html). Can someone please tell me how to do it?

Comment: First you `Transpose` the two vectors, and plot points. Then you can use `FindFit` to find the best fit for your data. e.g. `ylist = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, 20]` , `xlist = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, 20]` and `pts = Transpose[{xlist, ylist}]` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some fake data

```
SeedRandom[42];
timeWind11=MovingAverage[Sort@RandomReal[1,51+9],10];
lammdaWind11=MovingAverage[RandomReal[1,51+9],10];
```

your current interpolations

```
lammdaWind11I = ListInterpolation[lammdaWind11];

timeWind11I = ListInterpolation[timeWind11];

Show[
ListPlot[{timeWind11,lammdaWind11},PlotStyle->{Red,Blue},PlotTheme->"Scientific"],
Plot[Evaluate@{timeWind11I[n],lammdaWind11I[n]},{n,1,51},PlotStyle->Thin]
]
```

[image]

My proposed solution uses [`Interpolation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpolation.html) and arranges the data to the correct format using [`Transpose`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html)

[image]

```
if=Interpolation[Transpose@{timeWind11,lammdaWind11}];

Show[
 ListPlot[
  Transpose@{timeWind11,lammdaWind11}
  ,Joined->False
  ,PlotTheme->"Scientific"
 ],
 Plot[if[t],{t,Sequence@@MinMax[timeWind11]}]
]
```

[image]